# Keras fit generator slow

Tags: python, keras, multiprocessing, gpu, virtual-memory

Keras [`fit_generator`](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) is very slow. The GPU is not used constantly in training, sometimes it's usage drops to 0%. Even on 4 workers and `multiproceesing=True`.

Also, the processes of the script are requesting too much virtual memory and are with a D status, [*uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)*](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/process-status-d-44989/%7D).

I already tried different combinations of `max_queue_size` but it didn't work.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HArOL.png) GPU Usage

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRlvP.png) of Processes Virtual Memory and Status

[Hardware Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBtRA.png)
GPU = Titan XP 12Gb

Code of Data Generator Class

```
import numpy as np
import keras
import conf


class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    'Generates data for Keras'
    def __init__(self, list_IDs, labels, batch_size=32, dim=(conf.max_file, 128),
                 n_classes=10, shuffle=True):
        'Initialization'
        self.dim = dim
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.labels = labels
        self.list_IDs = list_IDs
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.on_epoch_end()

    def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
        return int(np.floor(len(self.list_IDs) / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        'Generate one batch of data'
        # Generate indexes of the batch
        indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]

        # Find list of IDs
        list_IDs_temp = [self.list_IDs[k] for k in indexes]

        # Generate data
        X, y = self.__data_generation(list_IDs_temp)

        return X, y

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        'Updates indexes after each epoch'
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.list_IDs))
        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    def __data_generation(self, list_IDs_temp):
        'Generates data containing batch_size samples' # X : (n_samples, *dim, n_channels)
        # Initialization
        X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim))
        y = np.empty((self.batch_size, conf.max_file, self.n_classes))
        # Generate data
        for i, ID in enumerate(list_IDs_temp):
            # Store sample
            X[i, ] = np.load(conf.dir_out_data+"data_by_file/" + ID)

            # Store class
            y[i, ] = np.load(conf.dir_out_data +
                            'data_by_file/' + self.labels[ID])

        return X, y
```

Code of python script

```
training_generator = DataGenerator(partition['train'], labels, **params)

validation_generator = DataGenerator(partition['validation'], labels, **params)

model.fit_generator(generator = training_generator,
                    validation_data = validation_generator,
                    epochs=steps,
                    callbacks=[tensorboard, checkpoint],
                    workers=4,
                    use_multiprocessing=True,
                    max_queue_size=50)
```

Comment: Saying "very slow" is subjective, how long does an epoch take? Have you considered that GPU is not the bottleneck, but reading files from the filesystem?

Comment: It can be because of reading time of filesystem. It is "very slow" relative to using just `fit`. The GPU is not fully used so I think the problem is probably not with it.

Comment: fit and fit_generator don't do the same thing, so its not a fair comparison. You should find a way to do less IO for your problem, for example, having large number of small files to read is always going to be a problem.

Comment: So how to minimize this problem for `fit_generator`? I can't use `fit` due to a large amount of data.

Comment: Optimize the generator function so it is fast and uses the minimum amount of IO.

Comment: @RenanCunha +1 I'm having the same problem here...did you find any solution to this?

Comment: What helped me a little was loading all the Classes values at once and use generator just for the input data. But even that did not result in a good performance, maybe because I use an HDD instead of SSD. So I converted my data to float16 to fit the PC ram.

Comment: This helped 
https://medium.com/@moritzkrger/speeding-up-keras-with-tfrecord-datasets-5464f9836c36
https://keras.io/examples/mnist_tfrecord/

Comment: Using the `fit_generator()` without the multiprocessing is soo much faster

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Tensorflow 2.0, you might be hitting this bug: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33024

Work arounds are:

- Call `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()` at the start of the code
- Use `model.fit` rather than `model.fit_generator`. The former supports generators anyway.
- Downgrade to TF 1.14

Regardless of Tensorflow version, these principles apply:

- Limit how much disk access you are doing, this that is often a bottleneck.
- Check the batch size in both training and validation. A batch size of 1 in validation is going to be very slow.

There does seem to be an issue though with generators being slow in 1.13.2 and 2.0.1 (at least). https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12683

Comment: try using a larger batch size